# error: Non-nullable instance field must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

error: Non-nullable instance field 'pickedImage' must be initialized.
error: Non-nullable instance field 'textResult' must be initialized.
error: The non-nullable variable 'hasilScan' must be initialized.

```
  File pickedImage;
  String textResult;
  static String hasilScan;
```

Answer (score 0):

In flutter after null safety was enabled, you can't leave a variable without assiging  a value to it.
you can either use `late` modifier, but you have to assign a value to it later

```
late String textResult;
```

or make it nullable using null check operator

```
String? textResult;
```

or just assign a value to it :

```
String textResult = 'some text';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats simple either assign a value to variable or make variable type Nullablae using ?.
Like File? File;
String? string;